# Find the particular solution of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}y' =0$, with $y(1) = 9$.

I get:

$\sqrt{y}dy = -\sqrt{x}dx \Rightarrow \frac{2}{3}y^{\frac{3}{2}} = -\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$.

What should I do from here?

Comment: Have you tried filling in $y(1) = 9 \Leftrightarrow x=1\land y=9$?

Comment: Yes, I get $18 + \frac{2}{3} = C$. Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe if you manipulate the equation to $y = ...$ and then fill it in the DE. If the LHS  = RHS it should work out. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes, it is${]$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply through by $3/2$ and rename $\frac32 C = c$

$$ y^{3/2} = c - x^{3/2} $$

The initial condition $y(1)=9$ gives $c = 28$. Solving for $y$ gives

$$ y^{3/2} = 28 - x^{3/2} \implies y = (28-x^{3/2})^{2/3} $$

Answer (score 0):

Solve it by separation of variables because it's a separable differential equation:

$$
\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}y' =0\\
\sqrt{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=-\sqrt{x}\\
\int\sqrt{y}\frac{dy}{dx}\,dx=-\int\sqrt{x}\,dx\\
\int\sqrt{y}\,dy=-\int\sqrt{x}\,dx\\
\frac{2\sqrt{y^3}}{3}+C_1=-\frac{2\sqrt{x^3}}{3}+C_2\\
\sqrt{y^3}=-\sqrt{x^3}+C\\
y=\sqrt[3]{(C-\sqrt{x^3})^2}
$$

Now that we have found the general solution, we can use the initial condition $y(1)=9$ to find a particular solution:

$$
y(1)=9\implies \sqrt[3]{(C-\sqrt{1^3})^2}=9\implies C=28
$$

Your final answer is $y=\sqrt[3]{(28-\sqrt{x^3})^2}$.